# What could be changing my WP password and blocking plugins from installing?

Tags: multisite, wp-admin

My WP root password stopped working. I was able to restore it and reinstall WP 6.2 from scratch, but after every several hours, the new password stops working and I have to restore it. In addition, I get this message when I try to update any plugins

```
Update failed: 403 Forbidden Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

The apache log isn't much more helpful,

```
"POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 403 277
```

Comment: Could be your server issue where you (the user) doesn't have permission to modify filesystem. You can ask your hosting provider to fix the issue.

Comment: The password's not working appears to have been the result of malware , which I removed. The forbidden error is still occurring.

Comment: I am my hosting provider. ;-) All permissions are correct to my knowledge. Strangely, I was able to update my themes and plugins in Firefox. (The forbidden errors occur in Chrome.)

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be due to some interaction between WordPress and the Google Chrome browser I was using to effect these changes. In another browser, the updates work. They also work in an Chrome incognito window.